# Open and move files across multiple directories

Tags: python

I have a bunch of directories, each containing one .txt file, containing a list of filenames i want to move to that directory. So, I want to iterate through each directory, read in the .txt, then copy the names in that same to the same directory containing the text file.

So my original directory is:

```
original = "path/to/direc"
destination = glob.glob(path + '/*_winning_comparisons_new')
```

Where the names of the directories of interest contain the string
`/*_winning_comparisons_new`

Each `destination` contains a single .txt folder, which looks like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
…
```

So I want to move the names within the `.txt` folder to the destination directory. They are located in the `original` directory.

I wrote the code below to do it

```
original = "path/to/direc/"
destination = glob.glob(path + '/*_winning_comparisons_new') 

#go to each directory and read the text file. 
for i in destination:
    print(i)
    for filenames in os.listdir(i):
        with open(os.path.join(i, filenames)) as myfile:
            content = myfile.read()
            print(content)
```

Now, I am stuck on the "copy the filenames in content" part. Any tips on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you only `open` the file it it is a `.txt` file?  Can you provide a more concrete example of what you want this to do?

Comment: There is only a .txt file in each of these directories. I can elaborate on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `shutil` at the begin of your program:

```py
import shutil
```

I guess, `i` stores the path to the destination folder?
Within your `with` statement do the following:

```py
content = myfile.read().splitlines()
for src_file in content:
    shutil.copy(src_file, i)
```

Hope, I understood your question correctly.

Comment: This is exactly it.